# rails RESTful updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, should you be able to update a field using a URL.
Is that called RESTful?

For example, should something similar to this work to update workorder.wostatus_id for workorder with id=2?

```
http://localhost:5000/workorders/2?wostatus_id=4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you've provided that shouldn't work as updates should be performed via a `PUT` request although if the URL was requested via `PUT` then it should work.

Remember the idea is that:

- `GET` to access and retrieve data
- `PUT` to update data
- `POST` to create data
- `DELETE` to remove data

EDIT: Often the actual parameter names can vary depending on the controller implementation so in rails you often find `?workorder[wostatus_id]=4`, where it will reference the model name.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to call a URL to perform any updates, but you'll need to use a POST or PUT request. POST to create, PUT to update, but I believe Rails uses "data-action" attribute for PUTs, then actually calls POST behind the scenes.

Just putting the URL in a browser, like the one you gave, will by default perform a GET request, which should never be used to change data, only to retrieve it.

Here's a good tutorial that explains the basics of REST: [REST API tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/)

The [Rest for Rails screencast](https://peepcode.com/products/rest-for-rails-2) is pretty helpful, as well.